# Using data from CSV to make directories

Tags: python

i have a .csv file such as the following:

```
name1,name2,name3 and so on
```

using Python script i am trying to have it read the .csv and make directories for each value
eg: `name1,name2,name3` will create these directories :`name1 and name2 and name3`

this is my code so far:

```
import os
import fileinput
textFile = 'E:/Videos/Movies/subtest/dirlist.csv'
path = "E:/Videos/Movies/subtest/"

#generate a txt file with the current names of the directories
def makeFile():
    # Open a file
    dirs = os.listdir( path )
    # This would print all the files and directories
    for file in dirs:
        #open the file
        tFO = open(textFile, "ab+")
        #write to the file, seprating each item with "||"
        tFO.write( file + ',' ) 
        #print output
        print ( file )
        #prints confirmation
        print 'file printed!'
        #close the file
        tFO.close()
    mainMenu()

def makeDirs():
    #open textFile as read only and set its varible as myListRead
    myListRead = open(textFile, 'rb+')
    #reads the x amount of lines and stores it as str
    str = myListRead.read();
    for line in str:
        os.makedirs(path + str)
    print 'directories created:', str
```

running this code creates the .csv as i intended, but when i run makeDirs() it makes the directory name all of the .csv (name1,name2,name3 as the foldername)

Comment: Can you clarify what is wrong with your code?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Can you print out what path + str is from your os.makedirs and post it here?

Comment: @sihrc path + str yields: E:/Videos/Movies/subtest/dirlist.txt,run.py

Answer (score 2):

Your problems become immediately obvious if you add some `print`
statements to your code.

Given an input file that looks like:

```
name1,name2,name3
```

The following code:

```
str = myListRead.read();
for line in str:
    print 'LINE:', line
```

Would print:

```
LINE: n
LINE: a
LINE: m
LINE: e
LINE: 1
LINE: ,
LINE: n
LINE: a
LINE: m
LINE: e
LINE: 2
LINE: ,
LINE: n
LINE: a
LINE: m
LINE: e
LINE: 3
LINE:
```

That is, you're iterating over characters, not comma delimited items.
The `read()` method reads in the entire file as a single string.  You
get a sequence of characters, not a sequence of lines.

If you want to iterate over lines in a file, you don't need to call
`read()`, you can just to this:

```
myListRead = open(textFile, 'rb+')
for line in myListRead:
    print 'LINE:', line
```

Which would yield:

```
LINE: name1,name2,name3
```

Of course, you're going to need to split this line on commas.  You
could do this:

```
for line in myListRead:
    for item in line.strip().split(','):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, item))
        print 'created', item
```

You could also think about using the built-in `csv` module for parsing
your CSV file, although that may be overkill for your particular use
case.

Comment: Thanks! The last part of code there worked for me, I also had to create the directories to a new file path as i can't create 2 of the same directory.